# ng-style ternary condition always resulting false

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I am working with angularJS and node.js
here a problem is occurring that 'ng-style' ternary condition always results as false while it must be true.
here is my code :

```
           <div class="msg-single" 
               ng-repeat="message in messages"
               ng-style="{'cursor': msessage.toid === socketId ? 'not-allowed':'pointer'}">
               {{message.fromid === socketId ? 'You': message.name }} : {{ message.msg }}
           </div>
```

In above code, the ng-style is resulting false on both sender socket as well as receiver socket (pointer).
while in next line, message.fromid === socketId it works fine means it results as true at same socketId but false at another socket id where the sender is sending message.

The related .js code is:

```
socket.on('getMsg', (data) => {

            socket.broadcast.to(data.toid).emit('sendMsg',{
                msg:data.msg,
                name:data.name,
                fromid:data.fromid,
                toid:data.toid
            });
            socket.emit('sendMsg',{
                msg:data.msg,
                name:data.name,
                fromid:data.fromid,
                toid:data.toid
            });

        });

socket.on('sendMsg', (data) => {
    //console.log('send');
            $scope.messages.push(data);
       });
```

Can you suggest me what could be the possible reason ? and Solution .

Comment: msessage.toid is missspelled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why but I think you can try this:

```
ng-style="{message.toid === socketId} && {'cursor': 'not-allowed'} || {'cursor':'pointer'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you:

```
ng-style="message.toid === socketId ? {'cursor':'not-allowed'} : {'cursor':'pointer'}"
```

Or:

```
ng-style="{{message.toid === socketId}} ? {'cursor':'not-allowed'} : {'cursor':'pointer'}"
```